# Make Java Runnable run continuously

Tags: java

How to make a `class` that implements a `java.lang.Runnable` interface to run continuously without blocking the whole application.

For example:

```
private void startHandler(UsbDevice d) {
    if (mLoop != null) {
        mConnectionHandler.onErrorLooperRunningAlready();
        return;
    }
    mLoop = new UsbRunnable(d);
    mUsbThread = new Thread(mLoop);
    mUsbThread.start();
}
```

Need to make the `mLoop`'s run() method to run continuously. UsbRunnable implements the Runnable interface.

Comment: What's `UsbRunnable`s code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make a class that implements a java.lang.Runnable interface to run continuously without blocking the whole application.

You need two things:

- A loop inside the `run()` method
- A call which blocks, usually by communicating with your device

```
public class USBRunnable implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
      while (isRunning) {
          data = readFromUSBDevice();  // waits until data is available, returns the data read
          processData(data);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to put a loop in `run`:

```
public void run() {
    while (!terminationCondition) {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

`run` should model the total work the `Runnable` needs to do, not just one iteration of that work. So if it needs to do repeated work until it's stopped, you use a loop to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Can have a while (true){......} Loop inside the run method of the class that implements runnable. Can mark this thread as deamon.